# How to write 'coffee shop' correctly

Tags: word-usage, hyphens, compounds

I read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059922/probability-bus-stop-and-coffee-shop)  question on math.stackexchange.com. I am not sure if it is correct to write coffee shop' using a hyphen in between. Please advise.

Ex:- coffee-shop

Ps:- Can we consider it as a compound noun? (woodshop is a compound noun as far as I know)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both versions are used. If we take [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coffee-shop%2Ccoffee%20shop%2Ccoffeeshop&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccoffee%20-%20shop%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccoffee%20shop%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccoffeeshop%3B%2Cc0) as a usage indication, you can see that the non-hyphenated version is by far the more common one.

Note that, unlike "coffee shop",  [coffeehouse](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coffee%20house%2Ccoffeehouse%2Ccoffee-house&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccoffee%20house%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccoffeehouse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccoffee%20-%20house%3B%2Cc0) , is more commonly written as one word.

Answer (score 3):

"Coffee shop" without the hyphen is the usual way to write it, but I think "coffee-shop" with a hyphen is fine too.  There are a lot of exceptions like this in English, i.e. re-read or reread.

Comment: I often see "**coffee shop**" with an [**`**] over the final **e** in the word "**coffee**"

Comment: @SovereignSun Where do you see that? Are you thinking of [café](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/caf%C3%A9)?

Comment: @ColleenV Maybe, can't say for sure. I guess you are right.

Comment: Spelling "coffeè" is just an affectation. It emulates Italian caffè, but is not part of English. Don't put an accent on coffee.

Comment: I've never seen "*coffee-shop*" written by native English speakers.

Comment: I didn't say it was common, but I am sure it is possible. For instance, in English, "common law" is usually two words even when it acts as an adjective, but people sometimes hyphenate it (I have).

Comment: Just because some people write a word with a hyphen doesn't make it correct.

Comment: freedictionary.com has a spot for "coffee-shop" with a hyphen if you type it in, but then it just redirects you to "coffee".